# Ruby/rails / chaining methods

Tags: ruby

Given the following example :

```
apply_filter_a(
 apply_filter_b(
  apply_filter_c(
    active_record_dataset
  )
 )
)

...

def apply_filter_a(records)
  # some more complex than 
  ...
end

def apply_filter_b(records)
  # some other complex logic filtering the active record dataset
  ...
end

def apply_filter_c(records)
  # some other complex logic filtering the active record dataset
  ...
end
```

How to simplify the nested method syntax (`apply_filter_a(apply_filter_b(...`)) in a more simple way ? is it possible to apply methods from an array of methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [`yield_self`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/yield_self) method, or you can use its alias [`then`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/then). You can pipe calls one by one, each of your filter methods must return an active record relation.

```rb
apply_filter_a(active_record_dataset)
  .then { |records| apply_filter_b(records) }
  .then { |records| apply_filter_c(records) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this sort of folding operation with [`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

First, we need an array of methods. We can get those using [`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Object.html#method-i-method).

```
my_filters = [method(:apply_filter_c), method(:apply_filter_b), method(:apply_filter_a)]
```

Then we can use `inject` on the list of filters to apply to an initial value.

```
my_filters.inject(active_record_dataset) { |acc, f| f.call acc }
```